# Autocomplete text box. Selecting a value

Tags: vb.net, textbox

good day!
there is a textbox autocomplete code

```
  Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim day_source As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        day_source.AddRange(System.Enum.GetNames(GetType(DayOfWeek)))
        PrepareTextBox(TextBox1, day_source, AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend)
    End Sub
    Private Sub PrepareTextBox(ByVal txt As TextBox, ByVal source As AutoCompleteStringCollection, ByVal mode As AutoCompleteMode)
        txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source
        txt.AutoCompleteMode = mode
    End Sub
```

Tell me how you can display a message with the name of the selected value when you select a value?

Comment: There is no event for that. Unless you want to get into unmanaged code, you would just have to handle the `TextChanged` event and note whether it followed a `KeyPress` event, although that still won't account for text being pasted in. Why should it matter anyway? It seems like you are trying to make a `TextBox` work like a `ComboBox` when you could just use a `ComboBox`.

Comment: The KeyDown event fires with e.KeyCode = 13 when the user presses Enter or Double Clicks on an item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The KeyDown event fires with e.KeyCode = 13 when the user presses Enter or Double Clicks on an item in the list.

```vb
  Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
            MsgBox(TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
```